# How to pass a parameter from vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, parameters, stored-functions

I have a Program that will auto run each night, run a query, and email results.  In my program I am calling a function as part of the query...  What i'd like to is pass the date the program is run as the parameter. (@startdate and @enddate)  @startdate will always be "today's" date at 00:00:00 and enddate will always be "Todays date" at 23:59:59.  So for example.  If the program was run tonight, it would pass 1/31/13 as the date.  Tomorrow, it would pass 2/1/13 as the date, the next date 2/2/13, etc.  If I can do this at the query level that is fine as well...  Below is my code:

```
SELECT
  SUM(QTY) AS Discounts
FROM
  dbo.fFinancialDataFull('Date Range Report', @startdate , @enddate, '1', '1', 'ALL', 'ALL', 'ALL', 'ALL', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1') AS fFinancialDataFull_1
WHERE
  (ReportCategoryID = 62)) AS unlimitedtbl
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

//These are the date variables.. if u need them seperately

```
Dim TodayDt As DateTime = DateTime.Today
Dim Tomorrow As DateTime = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)
Dim TodayEnd as DateTime
TodayEnd = Tomorrow.AddSeconds(-1)
```

//This is the SQL Command that executes in SQL Server

```
  SELECT
  SUM(QTY) AS Discounts
FROM
  dbo.fFinancialDataFull('Date Range Report', startdate , enddate, '1', '1', 'ALL', 'ALL', 'ALL', 'ALL', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1') AS fFinancialDataFull_1
WHERE ReportCategoryID = 62
 AND startdate = TodayDt
 AND enddate = TodayEnd AS unlimitedtbl
```

//This is the function u need to write to make the same SQL run on VB

```
Public Function GetValueByDates() As String
    Dim TodayDt As DateTime = DateTime.Today
    Dim Tomorrow As DateTime = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)
    Dim TodayEnd as DateTime
    TodayEnd = Tomorrow.AddSeconds(-1)
    Dim ReportCategoryID = 62

    Dim sql As String = "       SELECT
      SUM(QTY) AS Discounts
    FROM
      dbo.fFinancialDataFull('Date Range Report', startdate , enddate, '1', '1', 'ALL', 'ALL', 'ALL', 'ALL', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1') AS fFinancialDataFull_1
    WHERE ReportCategoryID = @ReportCategoryID
     AND startdate = @TodayDt
     AND enddate = @TodayEnd AS unlimitedtbl"

    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string here"), _
        cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, cn)

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@TodayDt", SqlDbTypes.DateTime).Value = TodayDt
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@TodayEnd", SqlDbTypes.DateTime).Value = TodayEnd
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReportCategoryID", SqlDbTypes.int).Value = ReportCategoryID 
     Return cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()
    End Using
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

To call this function in VB.Net code, you should place the function call in a Stored Procedure and call this Procedure from VB.NET, passing the parameters as follows:

```
 Dim sqlcmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand()
 sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
 sqlcmd.CommandText = "PROCEDURE_NAME"
 sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@startdate", DateTime.Now.Date))
 sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@enddate", DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1)));
 Dim obj As Object = sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar()
```

If you can't create a Stored Procedure, you can do at the query level:

```
declare @startdate datetime
declare @enddate datetime

set @startdate = cast(floor(cast(getdate() as float))as datetime) -- truncate the time part
set @enddate = dateadd(S, -1, dateadd(d, 1, @startdate)) -- add 1 day, subtract 1 minute from today
```

Comment: I do not have the ability to create a stored procedure.  It's a database that is consistently synced.  I have no control over the synced info.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
Dim StartDate as string = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") & " 00:00:00"
Dim EndDate as string = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") & " 23:59:59"
```

I don't know what database server you are using. Try different date format if that didn't work, like `DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`

Comment: It's 2005.  I'll try this now, and let you know.